# Script for Google Earth Engine

Tags: javascript, png, google-earth-engine, geotiff

I need to convert Geotiff image file to PNG from Google Earth Engine, is this possible?

I created the following code, it generates a geotiff to export to Google Drive for later download and use the PNG image in Qgis.
After declaring parameters, image, and variables I show you the important point:

```
Map.addLayer(NDWI_table,{color:'red'}, 'vectors');

// Export result to Google Drive
Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: NDWI_table, 
  description: 'NDWI_table', 
  folder: 'proyecto1', 
  fileFormat: 'SHP'
});

//Export Geotiff
//rango de NDVI
var ndviRange1 = 0.344;

// Calculation NDVI

var ndvi1 = img_sent2.normalizedDifference(['B11','B8A','B3']).rename('NDVI');
var ndviMask1 = ndvi1.gte(ndviRange1); //geater than

// Updating the mask
var NdviData=ndvi1.updateMask(ndviMask1);

//Export this mask
Export.image.toDrive({
      image: NdviData,
      description: 'NDWI_image',
      folder:'Proyecto2',
      scale: 05,
      crs: 'EPSG:5070',
      formatOptions: {
    cloudOptimized: true
  }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think we can't download other than GeoTIFF, Shapefile and CSV file in Google Earth Engine.
You can do one thing download the data in GeoTiff format and open that in offline software's like QGIS or ArcGIS.
Create a map by using that tiff file, by doing this thing you can easily export in png, jpeg, jpg etc.,